# Hot questions list does not serve a https

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, ssl

Visit https://stackexchange.com/  (in secure mode).
The list of hot questions listed in the page are linked in "http" mode and not https

Can this please be changed to use https?

Answer (score 1):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Why did this happen? I am unsure but I can blame the fact that SE wants to [move on from HTTP to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time). With this major change changing most, if not all, Stack Exchange links to begin with `https://` rather than `http://`. Also, if we inspect the source code in the HNQ, we see that all links start with `https://`:

[image]